# Laravel Calculate AVG of a related column

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to calculate average ratings of a related column. The relationship (1->many) is in between Merchant & ClientFeedbackReviews Models.

**Merchant Model**

```
[Merchant Model]
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

public function clientFeedbacks() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\ClientFeedbackReviews'); //, 'merchant_id', 'id');
```

**ClientFeedbackReviews**

```
 ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: 

class ClientFeedbackReviews extends Model {

protected $table = 'client_feedback_merchants';
public function forMerchant() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Merchant', 'merchant_id', 'id');
}

public function byClient() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Clients', 'client_id', 'id');
}
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

I need to get average ratings of all the merchant (*as a PART of a query where I am calculating results-the merchants according to nearby distances, given location or a using search string depending upon the Request Data*)

I have tried almost everything I found on internet but couldn't able to get  'average_ratings' key-value in results.

Here is one the many solutions that I have tried and pasting here as an example

```
 /////// query continued //////////

 $getMerchantQuery = $getMerchantQuery->with(['clientFeedbacks' => function($query) {

            $query->select(DB::raw('AVG( stars) AS average_rating'));
        }]);

 /////// query continued //////////
```

and this the what I am getting ALWAYS - empty array for client_feedbacks whereas I want the average_rating right there.

```
  {
"id": 1,
"user_id": 2,
"company_name": "Best Salon",
"primary_contact": "111111111",
"company_st_address": "Office # 62",
"company_location": "Abc",
"company_city": null,
"company_state": null,
"company_country": null,
"company_zip": null,
"company_lat": "27.9506",
"company_long": "82.4572",
"logo_image": "449cbdf0-12ba-11e7-bc65-b7fa1731e4d5.jpeg",
"is_fav_by_client_count": 3,
"client_feedbacks_count": 1,
"user_details": {
  "id": 2,
  "email": "client@lir.com"
},
"client_feedbacks": []
```

}

What are the options do we have to calculate avg of a related table ?

============ EDIT

However this returns results but not sure how to get the AVERAGE in client_feedbacks key.

```
      $getMerchantQuery = $getMerchantQuery->with('clientFeedbacks');
```

as

```
{
"id": 1,
"user_id": 2,
"company_name": "Best Salon",
"primary_contact": "111111111",
"company_st_address": "Office # 62",
"company_location": "abc",
"company_city": null,
"company_state": null,
"company_country": null,
"company_zip": null,
"company_lat": "27.9506",
"company_long": "82.4572",
"logo_image": "449cbdf0-12ba-11e7-bc65-b7fa1731e4d5.jpeg",
"is_fav_by_client_count": 3,
"client_feedbacks_count": 1,
"user_details": {
  "id": 2,
  "email": "client@lbb.com"
},
"client_feedbacks": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "client_id": 1,
    "merchant_id": 1,
    "stars": 4,
    "review_notes": "good client",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
  }
]
```

}

Comment: It's been almost 3 days and no answer yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. So this did the job following this [blog](https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-hasmany-relation-count-efficiently/) :

```
    public function avgFeedback() {

    return $this->hasMany('App\ClientFeedbackReviews', 'merchant_id', 'id')
                    ->selectRaw('merchant_id,AVG(client_feedback_merchants.stars) AS average_rating')
                    ->groupBy('merchant_id');
}

public function getavgFeedbackAttribute() {
    // if relation is not loaded already, let's do it first
    if ($this->relationLoaded('commentsCount'))
        $this->load('avgFeedback');

    $related = $this->getRelation('avgFeedback');

    // then return the count directly
    return ($related) ? (int) $related->average_rating : 0;
}
```

and I have used it as follows:

```
    //////// query continued /////////

    $getMerchantQuery = $getMerchantQuery->with('avgFeedback');

    ///////  query continued //////////
```